# Script error: Invalid bucket name

Tags: aws

I have a task to go through all the s3 buckets in my account and find the ones that are not encrypted by the default kms encryption. I have drafted the following two commands with a loop to go through each bucket name and check its encryption level

```
output="$(aws s3api list-buckets --query 'Buckets[*].Name')"

for i in $output; do aws s3api get-bucket-encryption --bucket $i; done
```

The script gives me the following error:

```
Invalid bucket name ""cdktoolkit-stagingbucket-30v8nlr122c0",": Bucket name must match the regex "^[a-zA-Z0-9.\-_]{1,255}$" or be an ARN matching the regex "^arn:(aws).*:s3:[a-z\-0-9]+:[0-9]{12}:accesspoint[/:][a-zA-Z0-9\-]{1,63}$"
```

it works for the first part now, the output variable doesn't contain the question mark anymore, thanks for the help.

But as i go further, when i ran the second cli command "for i in $output; do aws s3api get-bucket-encryption --bucket $i; done", it returns another JSON format output, how could I grep the bucket name without AES256 encryption enabled.

```
Jasons-Air:~ jason$ for i in $output; do aws s3api get-bucket-encryption --bucket $i; done
{
    "ServerSideEncryptionConfiguration": {
        "Rules": [
            {
                "ApplyServerSideEncryptionByDefault": {
                    "SSEAlgorithm": "aws:kms"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}

An error occurred (ServerSideEncryptionConfigurationNotFoundError) when calling the GetBucketEncryption operation: The server side encryption configuration was not found

An error occurred (ServerSideEncryptionConfigurationNotFoundError) when calling the GetBucketEncryption operation: The server side encryption configuration was not found

An error occurred (ServerSideEncryptionConfigurationNotFoundError) when calling the GetBucketEncryption operation: The server side encryption configuration was not found
{
    "ServerSideEncryptionConfiguration": {
        "Rules": [
            {
                "ApplyServerSideEncryptionByDefault": {
                    "SSEAlgorithm": "AES256"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

I tried to append "--query 'ServerSideEncryptionConfiguration[*].Rules[*].ApplyServerSideEncryptionByDefault[*].SSEAlgorithm'" to my command, but it shows result as "null" instead of "AES256".

```
Jasons-Air:~ jason$ for i in $output; do aws s3api get-bucket-encryption --bucket $i --query 'ServerSideEncryptionConfiguration[*].Rules[*].ApplyServerSideEncryptionByDefault[*].SSEAlgorithm'; done
null

An error occurred (ServerSideEncryptionConfigurationNotFoundError) when calling the GetBucketEncryption operation: The server side encryption configuration was not found

An error occurred (ServerSideEncryptionConfigurationNotFoundError) when calling the GetBucketEncryption operation: The server side encryption configuration was not found

An error occurred (ServerSideEncryptionConfigurationNotFoundError) when calling the GetBucketEncryption operation: The server side encryption configuration was not found
null
null
null
```

Comment: What does `aws s3api list-buckets --query 'Buckets[*].Name'` return? (Please [add to your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/593068/edit), and if the information is sensitive replace it with made-up data that exactly matches the style of the real output.)

Comment: ```Jasons-Air:~ jason$ aws s3api list-buckets --query 'Buckets[*].Name'
[
    "cdktoolkit-stagingbucket-30v8nlr122c0",
    "elasticbeanstalk-us-east-1-194639014949",
    "elasticbeanstalk-us-west-1-194639014949",
    "elasticbeanstalk-us-west-2-194639014949",
    "intangible-dev-terraform-state",
    "intangible-ssp-global-tf-states",
    "testbucketwithencryptionenabled",
    "thedevopguy"
]
```

Comment: It looks like it returns all the bucket names with a double quotation mark. Is there a way I can remove the quotation mark ?

Comment: It returns a JSON document. You may want to pass the result of the `aws` command trough `jq -r '.[]'`.

Comment: it works by using the jq filter. but the result of the loop still shows a json output. If i want to just grep the bucket name not having aws kms enabled ("SSEAlgorithm"= "aws:kms"), how could I filter the result. Sorry I am new to aws and just started my new job. the result is like this. 

```
Jasons-Air:~ jason$ for i in $output; do aws s3api get-bucket-encryption --bucket $i; done
{
    "ServerSideEncryptionConfiguration": {
        "Rules": [
            {
                "ApplyServerSideEncryptionByDefault": {
                    "SSEAlgorithm": "aws:kms"
                }
```

Comment: That's completely unreadable. As I asked before, please put the update [in your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/593068/edit)

Comment: I just updated my question. I appreciate your help, I will learn the "jq" command after this question.

Comment: Same as my first comment: what does `aws s3api list-buckets --query 'Buckets[*].Name'` return?

Comment: I resolved the issue by switching to boto3 library, it works now. Thank you all for the help.